# Improving QTimer Accuracy

Tags: c++, qt

I am using QT 4.7, and have a timer that will execute a function 2 times a second or 4 times a second based on what type of sound is required.

```
    void Keypad::SoundRequest(bool allowBeeps, int beepType)
    {

        // Clear any Previous active Timer
        if (sound1Timer->isActive() == true)
        {
            sound1Timer->stop();
        }
        else if(sound2Timer->isActive() == true)
        {
            sound2Timer->stop();
        }

        // Zero out main 
        (void) memset(&soundmain_t, (char) 0, sizeof(soundmain_t));
        // Zero out sound1
        (void) memset(&sound1_t, (char) 0, sizeof(sound1_t));
        // Zero out the sound2
        (void) memset(&sound2_t, (char) 0, sizeof(sound2_t));

        if (allowBeeps == true)
        {
            if(beepType == OSBEEP)
            {
                sound1Timer->start(500); // 250mS On / 250mS off called every 500mS = 2HZ
            }
            else if (beepType == DOORBEEP)
            {
                sound2Timer->start(250); // 125mS On / 125mS off called every 250mS = 4HZ
            }

        }
        else if (allowBeeps == false)
        {
            //Shut the Beeper Down

            if (sound1Timer->isActive() == true)
            {
                sound1Timer->stop();
            }
            else if(sound2Timer->isActive() == true)
            {
                sound2Timer->stop();
            }

            SOUND_BLAST(0, &soundmain_t);
        }


    }

Constructor:

    sound1Timer = new QTimer(this);
    sound2Timer = new QTimer(this);

    connect(sound1Timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(sound1Handler()));
    connect(sound2Timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(sound2Handler()));



SLOTS:

void Keypad::sound1Handler()
{
    // Sound a 250mS chirp
    SOUND_BLAST(0, &sound1_t);
}

// Public SLOT, Called by sound2Timer()
// Sounds a single 125mS Beep

void Keypad::sound2Handler()
{
    // Emit a Single 125mS chirp
    SOUND_BLAST(0, &sound2_t);
}
```

The Timer is mostly accurate, but it is not exactly 2Hz or 4Hz all the time. To improve the accuracy I was thinking of using a faster timer of say 25mS and letting it run, and every time it accumulates to 250mS or 125mS then sound the beep. However, I am not sure if this would make it more accurate.

Should I measure execution time with QElapsedTimer() and subtract the overhead to sound1Timer, and sound2Timer intervals? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: This will be always inaccurate alone because of other (user) events being processed in the main thread and blocking it. I'd consider using another dedicated thread for this and other means to schedule the beeps (some variant of sleep() might already do the trick)

Comment: You mean sleep() in the worker thread? I'm not sure if I want to introduce another thread, but as far as I can tell the thread for sound is output only and does not need to communicate with the main thread at all. So there shouldn't be any threading issues like semaphores as I can tell needed

Answer (score 3):

The accuracy of the timer is limited by the operating system. The Qt library uses operating system timers "under the covers".

If you need high accuracy I would have a timer subroutine that reads a hardware based clock to establish the timing of events. You'll need to dig into your operating system documentation to get the details.